# Sort an "inner" array ONLY by a specific keys value - with uasort()?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

```
Array opareas
(
[0] => Array
(
[name] = => array('opname1')

[subcats] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [amount] => 9883
                [perc] => 112.61394712853236
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [amount] => 1
                [perc] => 0.011394712853236098
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [amount] => 3679
                [perc] => 41.921148587055605
            )

    )

)

[1] => Array
(
[name] = => array('opname2')

[subcats] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [amount] => 12166
                [perc] => 56.8584380987989
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [amount] => 1473
                [perc] => 6.884142636818245
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [amount] => 955
                [perc] => 4.463242510632331
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [amount] => 6802
                [perc] => 31.789503201383372
            )

    )

)
```

PHP is excellent for sorting arrays, but I can't figure out what to use when having this issue.. Take a look of the array above.

I want to sort innner `subcats[]` array by the `perc`-key from lower to higher.

I want the result to be:

```
Array opareas
(
[0] => Array
(
[name] = => array('opname1')

[subcats] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [amount] => 1
                [perc] => 0.011394712853236098 //Lowest percentage value
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [amount] => 3679
                [perc] => 41.921148587055605
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [amount] => 9883
                [perc] => 112.61394712853236 //Highest percentage value
            )

    )

)

[1] => Array
(
[name] = => array('opname2');

[subcats] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [amount] => 955
                [perc] => 4.463242510632331 //Lowest percentage value
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [amount] => 1473
                [perc] => 6.884142636818245
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [amount] => 12166
                [perc] => 56.8584380987989
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [amount] => 6802
                [perc] => 31.789503201383372 //Highest percentage value
            )

    )

)
```

**I've tried with this:**

```
class whateverArray {

    private function sort_subcats_perc($a, $b) {               
        if ($a['subcats']['perc'] == $b['subcats']['perc'] ) {return 0;}
        return ( $a['subcats']['perc'] < $b['subcats']['perc'] ) ? -1 : 1;
    }

    public function showStuff() {
       $opareas = array(); //Given above

       //Sort subcat array from low to high based on perc-key
       uasort( $opareas, array( $this, 'sort_subcats_perc') );
    }

 );

}
```

**I don't want the actual** `opareas[0]` and `operas[1]` to switch position (is what happens when using the function I've tried) in the array, I only WANT the inner array subcats[] to change it's order based on perc-field/key. Is this possible with `uasort`? Or any other builtin of PHP excellent sorting functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to sort the sub-array, your comparison function needs to be a bit different. Then you can loop over the outer array by reference, so that the `subcats` will be sorted in place.

```
foreach ($opareas as &$value) {
    usort($value['subcats'], function($a, $b) {
        if ($a['perc'] > $b['perc']) return 1;
        if ($a['perc'] < $b['perc']) return -1;
        return 0;
    });
}
unset($value); // unset the reference after looping
```

You can use `usort`. You only need to use `uasort` if you care about the order of the keys in `subcats`.

Comment: Thank you! Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

```
$opareas = array(); //Given above
foreach($opareas as &$oparea){
 //Sort subcat array from low to high based on perc-key
 uasort( $oparea, array( $this, 'sort_subcats_perc') );
}
```

can be the solution here.

Comment: I couldn't get this to work by itself. I got illegal stringset subcats as warning.

Comment: That is because this is applying `uasort` with your `sort_subcats_perc` function to the second-level array (with keys "name" and "subcats") rather than to the innermost array.